# Find content inside quotes with duplicated quotes as well

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Folks,

Given a string to parse: `"Hello " & """world!"""`

Is it possible to end up with two matches as such: `"Hello"` and `"""world!"""`

I'm parsing VB code by the way, I'm trying to find *strings*. They are always in double quotes but duplicated double quotes inside are possible too similar to `@"Hello ""world!"""` in C#.

I'm open to any suggestions! My code parser will be written in C# btw.

I'm using `"[^"]+"` or `".+?"` as a basis for my trials but can't figure out how to get the desired result.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to write a VB parser from scratch?

Comment: @CodeCaster it's meant to find strings inside 13 year old legacy VB6 code which unfortunately has to be internationalized. I'm not even looking for _all_ strings but only that are set on properties such as `.Caption`.

Comment: My question is whether you are sure you want to reinvent the wheel. Parsers for various languages are freely available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `"[^"]+"` will stop at the first `"` after `"`, thus, you will not get the `"xx""z"""` substring as output, you will get just `"xx"`. Same with `".*?"` since you have not restricted the immediate context for the second `"` (and the second regex will also stumble at a newline symbol unless you specify the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag).

You can use the [following regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%7C%22%22)%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*%22&i=%22Hello%20%22%20%26%20%22%22%22world!%22%22%22) that will also match escaped sequences inside quotes:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^"\\]*)*"
```

Or a simplified for your case:

```
"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5B%5E%22%5D*(%3F%3A%22%22%5B%5E%22%5D*)*%22&i=%22Hello%20%22%20%26%20%22%22%22world!%22%22%22).

The latter regex explanation:

- `"` - match a `"`
- `[^"]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `"`
- `(?:""[^"]*)*` - match 0 or more sequences of ...

  - `""` - 2 consecutive quotes
  - `[^"]*` - 0 or more characters other than `"`
- `"` - match a `"`

In C#, you can use either verbatim string literal (where you need to use `""` to denote one literal `"`) or a regular string literal (where you need to use `\"` to denote a `"` and use double escapes for special regex metacharacters) to declare these regexes.

Verbatim:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"""[^""]*(?:""""[^""]*)*""");
```

Regular string literal:

```
var rx = new Regex("\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"");
```

I think a regular string literal declaration is cleaner in this case.

Comment: Great answer! The `(?:""[^"]*)*` group is the clever part I couldn't figure out :).

Comment: The `(?:""[^"]*)*` group  is an "unwrapped" version of `(?:""|[^"])*`, just more effecient because it involves less backtracking (though less readable :().